# Showing $R[x]\otimes R[y]\cong R[x,y]$ using certain corollary

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am to use the following corollary to show $R[x]\otimes R[y]\cong R[x,y]$

[Corollary 11, Chapter 10 Section 3, Dummit and Foote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmZvr.png)

I have come up with the map $\iota^{'}:R[x]\times R[y]\rightarrow R[x,y], \iota^{`}((a,b))=ab$. I have shown that this map is R-balanced and I have shown that the image generates $R[x,y]$ ($R$ has unity). I am confused about the second part of the corollary. First, I do not understand the reference back to Theorem 10, because in Theorem 10 we had three maps, and here we do not. Theorem 10 is below.

[Theorem 10, Chapter 10 Section 3, Dummit and Foote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRFwM.png)

where $\iota:R[x]\times R[y]\rightarrow R[x]\otimes R[y].\iota((a,b))=a\otimes b$

The second thing that I am confused about is, how do I show that all homomorphisms satisfy this property?

Comment: " Every balanced map factors through $\iota'$ " means: " For any abelian group $L$ and any balanced map $g:M\times N\to L$ there exists exactly one group homomorphism $h_g:D\to L$ such that $h_g\circ \iota'=g$ ".

Comment: Do you know how I can show this here? Or tell me how one would go about trying to make this claim.

Comment: I might be able to do the necessary verifications, but I would much rather leave it to people who are more familiar with the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the idea: Suppose $\varphi:R[x] \times R[y] \longrightarrow L$ is $R$-balanced.  We need to prove the existence of a unique group homomorphism $\tilde{\varphi}:R[x,y] \longrightarrow L$ such that $\tilde{\varphi} \circ \iota' = \varphi$.  What could this map $\tilde{\varphi}$ possibly be?  The answer is clear for monomials: $\tilde{\varphi}(rx^jy^k) = \varphi(rx^j,y^k)$, which is equal by $R$-balancedness to $\varphi(x^j,ry^k)$.  Since every element of $R[x,y]$ can be expressed as a finite $R$-linear combination of monomials.  We thus define: $\tilde{\varphi}(f(x,y)) = \tilde{\varphi}(\sum_{j,k} r_{j,k}x^jy^k) = \sum_{j,k} \varphi(r_{j,k}x^j,y^k)$.  You'll have to verify that this defines a homomorphism and that it is unique (i.e., if some other map $\psi:R[x,y] \longrightarrow L$ satisfies $\psi \circ \iota' = \varphi$, then $\psi = \tilde{\varphi}$), but that shouldn't be too hard.

By the way, this approach is very common in algebra.  Rather than constructing an explicit isomorphism between two objects (in this case, between $R[x,y]$ and $R[x] \otimes_R R[y]$) we instead show that the one object possesses a property that universally characterizes the other object (here, it is the unique factorization property.)  Since every $R$-balanced map $R[x] \times R[y] \longrightarrow L$ uniquely factors through $\iota':R[x] \times R[y] \longrightarrow R[x,y]$, and since the only abelian group with this property (up to isomorphism) is $R[x] \otimes_R R[y]$, we can conclude that the two are isomorphic.  Pretty slick! :)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me if I chose the correct map for $\iota^{`}$?

Comment: Your definition of $\iota'$ looks good to me!

Comment: I am actually having problems showing that the composition of our maps is equal to $\phi$ and showing that it is unique. Can you help with this? 

I consider $p(x)=\sum_ia_ix^i, q(y)=\sum_jb_jy^j$ where $p(x)q(y)=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{i,j}x^iy^j$. Then $(\tilde{\varphi}\circ \iota^{`})(p(x),q(y))=\tilde{\varphi}(p(x)q(y))=\tilde{\varphi}(\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{i,j}x^iy^j)=\sum_{i,y}\alpha_{i,j}\varphi(x^i,y^j)$

But how do I know $\varphi(p(x),q(y))=\sum_{i,y}\alpha_{i,j}\varphi(x^i,y^j)?$ without knowing what $\varphi$ does? Also, how would I go about showing that this is the only such map?

Comment: Let's take a step back. First, we note that $R[x,y]$ is generated (as an abelian group) by the set of monomials $rx^iy^j$, where $r \in R, i \ge 0, j \ge 0$.  Note that a group homomorphism $R[x,y] \longrightarrow L$ is uniquely determined by the values it takes on these monomials.  Said another way, two homomorphisms that equal one another on these monomials are equal on the entirety of $R[x,y]$.  ...and now I see I have a typo in the answer I posted.  Let me fix that and then I'll come back to the comments.

Comment: OK, so now let $\varphi:R[x] \times R[y] \longrightarrow L$ be $R$-balanced and suppose that $\psi:R[x,y] \longrightarrow L$ is a group homomorphism that satisfies $\psi \circ i' = \varphi$. Then $\psi(rx^iy^j) = \psi(i'(rx^i,y^j)) = \phi(rx^i,y^j)$. And this means that $\psi$ and $\tilde{\varphi}$ agree on all monomials.  Hence $\psi = \tilde{\varphi}$.

Comment: ahh, the typo was throwing me off. I could not get the scalars "back inside".